# Lock Usb Flash-Drive on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: ubuntu, usb-drive, lock

By security request, I need to set up Ubuntu desktops from my network to not allow the use of flashdrives or USB storage devices. But the USB mouse and keyboard should normally be charged. Is there a simple and effective way to prevent the use of these devices?

Comment: Remove the `usb-storage` kernel module.  It won't prevent people from transferring files elsewhere (if that's what you're trying to achieve), but it will stop them from using flash drives.

Comment: To whom does the restriction apply? Should super-users be allowed to use USB mass-storage devices? Ultimately you won't be able to prevent super-users to use them unless you remove all USB devices and glue the USB ports shut. For regular users it should be enough to override a few Udev rules that inform the kernel of the existence new block devices connected via USB.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Terminal and on the command prompt:

```
vi /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Append the following lines:

```
# disable usb storage access 
blacklist usb_storage
```

Also in order to use your USB keyboard and USB mouse, remove following lines:

[image: Blacklist Only USB Storage]

Save the file and restart the computer.

Comment: Not Working this solution writed by Amit24x7. Another solution?

Comment: Please explain what are the problems you are facing, is the above solution is not working at all? Are your USB mouse and keyboard also not working or is everything working even after the above workaround?